# Calling a Sheet Sub from a Userform

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016

I'm trying to build a macro that will read the dates from cells in my Worksheet and check them against a date (month and year) inputted into a Userform. To do this, I have the Userform call a Sub `Report` found within `Sheet1`. Integers which represent the user-inputted month and year are passed along with the call.

The error always occurs on the line: `Call Sheet1.Report(intMonth, intYear)`, which calls `Report`. The error reads: `Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error`.

Here's my abridged code, starting with the Userform:

```
Private Sub cmdOK_Click()

    'Transform month field into an integer (1-12)
    Dim intMonth As Integer
    Select Case cboMonth.Value
        Case Is = strJan 'January - 01
            intMonth = 1
        Case Is = strFeb 'February - 02
            intMonth = 2
        Case Is = strMar 'March - 03
            intMonth = 3
        'and so on...
    End Select

    'Read year field as an Integer
    Dim intYear As Integer
    intYear = txtYear.Value

    Call Sheet1.Report(intMonth, intYear)

End Sub
```

Next, here's the code from `Report`. It's incomplete as of yet, as I haven't been able to get past the call. As I mentioned earlier, I always hit the error on the Call line: `Call Sheet1.Report(intMonth, intYear)`.

```
Public Sub Report(myMonth As Integer, myYear As Integer)

    'Some incomplete code...
    'Like I said, the macro never gets past the call.

End Sub
```

Any ideas how to fix this? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Where have you defined **cboMonth** and **txtYear** ?

Comment: Your code example worked for me. Keep in mind that your usage of "Sheet1" as the object is the sheet object name and not the Worksheet name seen on the tab of the actual Excel sheet. If you want to call it by the Worksheet name try this:

`ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Report intMonth, intYear`

NOTE: You don't need the `Call` statement if you remove the parenthesis.

Comment: @angelofdev, cboMonth and txtYear refer to fields in the Userform, a combobox for the Month and a textbox for the Year, respectively. They don't get defined in the code, but I have some checks in place to make sure they are defined correctly in the Userform

Comment: @HackSlash, I tried your code with the Worksheet name and it worked! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you have proven that your code works with my suggestion:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Report intMonth, intYear
```

Let's take the advice provided by Mathieu. Click on the the sheet object in the Project view of your VBE window:

> VBAProject > Microsfot Excel Objects > Sheet1 (Sheet1)

The first part is the sheet object name, the second part in parenthesis is the Worksheet name as seen in the Excel tab. Bring up the Properties Window View either from the the "View" dropdown in the VBE or pressing F4. The first thing in the Worksheet properties window should be (name) and that's the object name you would call in your code. Change it to something descriptive like "Report". Then use a descriptive name for your macro like "Update".

Now you can make a new report by calling:

```
Report.Update intMonth, intYear
```

I use that naming convention because I assume your macro updates the report sheet. You can also take his advice on "model-view-presenter" code style but that is a bit out of the scope of your question.

Answer (score 3):

Having a `UserForm`'s default instance running the show is perhaps the easiest thing to do, but it's also a direct cause of many, many problems - from easily-introduced but hard-to-find bugs to maintenance and extensibility issues: the "nice & quick, works" solution is the "Smart UI" pattern, which works awesome for a *prototype*. Larger projects that constantly grow over time demand a smarter architecture.

Programmers call it "model-view-presenter". The *view* is the form. The data is the *model*, and then there's the *presenter* that coordinates it all.

> *Calling a Sheet Sub from a Userform*

Truth is, you don't. A modal `UserForm` is a *dialog*, whose role is nothing more than to collect the user's input. By making it only responsible for manipulating data, and leaving the macro/caller responsible for the control flow, you make the code more robust and easier to maintain - especially if the form can do many things.

Start with a simple `MonthlyReportParams` class module:

```
Option Explicit
Public Month As Integer ' encapsulate into properties to implement 
Public Year As Integer  ' logic for validation on assignment.

Public Property Get IsValid() As Boolean
    IsValid = Month >= 1 And Month <= 12 And _
              Year >= 1900 And Year <= 2100
End Property
```

Now all the `UserForm` needs to do, is to work with this data, this *model*.

```
Option Explicit
Private params As MonthlyReportParams
Private cancelled As Boolean

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set params = New MonthlyReportParams
End Sub

Public Property Get Model() As MonthlyReportParams
    Set Model = params
End Property

Public Property Set Model(ByVal value As MonthlyReportParams)
    Set params = value
    MonthBox.value = params.Month
    YearBox.value = params.Year
End Property

Public Property Get IsCancelled() As Boolean
    IsCancelled = cancelled
End Property

Private Sub MonthBox_Change()
    ' make sure the textboxes contain numeric values before assigning to Integer
    If IsNumeric(MonthBox.Value) Then params.Month = CInt(MonthBox.Value)
    OnValidate
End Sub

Private Sub YearBox_Change()
    ' make sure the textboxes contain numeric values before assigning to Integer
    If IsNumeric(YearBox.Value) Then params.Year = CInt(YearBox.Value)
    OnValidate
End Sub

Private Sub OkButton_Click()
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub CancelButton_Click()
    OnCancel
End Sub

Private Sub OnCancel()
    cancelled = True
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub OnValidate()
    OkButton.Enabled = Model.IsValid
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
' runs when form is just about to close
    If CloseMode = VbQueryClose.vbFormControlMenu Then
        ' user clicked the [X] button
        Cancel = True ' don't destroy the form
        OnCancel
    End If
End Sub
```

And now the macro that brings up this form can take back the control over what's going on: the form is no longer running the show, and we can read everything that's going on in one place:

```
Public Sub RunMonthlyReport(Optional ByVal targetSheet As Worksheet = Nothing)

    If targetSheet Is Nothing Then
        ' no sheet was specified; work of the ActiveSheet
        Debug.Assert Not ActiveSheet Is Nothing
        Set targetSheet = ActiveSheet
    End If

    ' create the model
    Dim m As MonthlyReportParams
    Set m = New MonthlyReportParams
    m.Month = Month(Now)
    m.Year = Year(Now)

    ' create the dialog, assign the model
    With New MonthlyReportParamsDialog
        Set .Model = m
        .Show ' next line only runs after dialog has closed

        If Not .IsCancelled Then
            ' run the report with the values in the model
            targetSheet.Report m.Month, m.Year
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Additional information about the benefits of this "reversal of responsibilities" can be found [in this article](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/), and further callback logic [in this article](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2018/05/08/apply-logic-for-userform-dialog/) - disclaimer: I wrote both; that blog is the official blog for the [Rubberduck](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck) VBIDE add-in OSS project, which I own.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply! So from what I understand, you're suggesting I implement a class with different properties to represent the input parameters (month and year). The Userform would then write onto that class, and the Report module would read off of it. This would offload the work from the Userform and onto the module, which would make it more robust. Is that correct?

Comment: @mykrus exactly! With minor tweaks it also makes the form reusable, too.

Answer (score 0):

HackSlash answered my question:

Your code example worked for me. Keep in mind that your usage of "Sheet1" as the object is the sheet object name and not the Worksheet name seen on the tab of the actual Excel sheet. If you want to call it by the Worksheet name try this: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Report intMonth, intYear NOTE: You don't need the Call statement if you remove the parenthesis. – HackSlash 7 mins ago

Comment: Note that accessing the sheet by name rather than by *code name* like you had it, makes it vulnerable to blow up as soon as a user renames the worksheet. If the sheet exists in `ThisWorkbook` at compile-time, set its `(Name)` property in the *properties* toolwindow (F4), by finding the sheet in the *project explorer* (Ctrl+R). Then you can use that name/identifier in code to refer to that sheet, without needing to dereference it from a `Worksheets` collection, or needing to declare a variable for it.

Comment: I added an answer. If you are satisfied you can delete this answer and mark a different one as the solution. I added the advice from Mathieu because he is correct.